# Make function keys behave as normal on a Lenovo laptop

Tags: windows, windows-10, lenovo-laptop, default-settings, button-remapping

How can I make buttons <kbd>F1</kbd>, ..., <kbd>F12</kbd> behave as normal on Windows 10 and as buttons specifically for my laptop when pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>...? By buttons which are specific for my laptop I mean volume buttons, light buttons, touchpad button and so on.

My laptop is Lenovo B50-10.

Comment: By either pressing the FN button or not

Comment: Laptop:
Swap Fn functions in BIOS

Comment: Many laptops have software that allows you to configure this. However, you haven't given any details about your laptop make and model.

Comment: @DavidPostill, I edited the question.

Comment: @Yaroslav Answer provided.

Comment: On other Lenovos, if you press <key>Fn</key> + <key>Esc</key>, it will drop the function lock.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### How can I make buttons F1, ..., F12 behave as normal on Windows 10

You can do this by making a change to your BIOS settings.

> Lenovo branded products:
>
> 1. Access the BIOS (See below for how to do this in Windows 10).
> 2. Once in the BIOS menu, select the "Configuration" tab.
> 3. Select "Hotkey Mode" and set to "Disabled".
>
>    [image]
> 4. Save and Exit the BIOS menu (press <kbd>F10</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Source [How to configure the function keys to not require use of the Fn key in Windows 8.1/10](https://support.lenovo.com/in/en/solutions/ht103044)

---

#### Recommended way to enter BIOS for IdeaPad, Lenovo Laptops

> 1. Launch Windows 8/8.1/10 desktop as per usual;
> 2. Restart the system. PC screen will dim off, but it will light up again and display "Lenovo: logo;
>
>    [image]
> 3. Press <kbd>F2</kbd>  (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> ) key when you see above screen.
>
> Note:
>
> - If the computer boots fast, you may miss the trick to press <kbd>F2</kbd>. If this happens, see the source link below for other
>     ways to enter the BIOS on Windows 10.

Source [Recommended way to enter BIOS for IdeaPad, Lenovo Laptops](https://support.lenovo.com/in/en/solutions/ht500216)

Comment: This is, of course, assuming your firmware has such an option. [Some Lenovo models](https://support.lenovo.com/ca/en/solutions/ht103044) must be configured through the Lenovo Settings app, or via the (Lenovo-customised) Windows *legacy* control panel keyboard panel. The Miix 700 specifically currently does not have the option at all. Though, yes, the B50 mentioned in the question probably does have the option in the firmware.

Comment: @Bob The B50 has that option documented in the [user manual](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/b50-10_ug_en.pdf)

Comment: On my Lenovo Thinkpad P51, the easiest way to make these and other  changes is from the **Control Panel** --> **Lenovo - Keyboard Manager** applet.

Comment: Will this work for linux mint ?

Comment: @EssaidiM No idea.

Answer (score 5):

> **Setting hotkey mode**
>
> By default, the hotkey functions are accessible by pressing the
>   appropriate hotkey. However, you can disable the hotkey mode in the
>   BIOS setup utility.
>
> To disable the hotkey mode:
>
> 1. Shut down the computer.
> 2. Press the Novo button and then select BIOS Setup.
> 3. In the BIOS setup utility, open the Configuration menu, and change the setting of HotKey Mode from Enabled to Disabled.
> 4. Open the Exit menu, and select Exit Saving Changes.
>
> **Note:** When hotkey mode is disabled, press the Fn key and the appropriate hotkey to access the corresponding hotkey function.
>
> Source:  [English User Guide - Lenovo B50-10 Laptop [PDF]](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/b50-10_ug_en.pdf) (Page 4)