# getting on a terminal shell on a lenovo t-440?

Tags: linux, debian, thinkpad, button-remapping

I have a lenovo t-440. I have had seizures and now can't remember what I used to do in order to have function keys behave as I like/want them to be. For instance on all my desktops its CTRL+ALT+Fn$` in order to get to a germinal shell One method which is shared by people here is [Make function keys behave as normal on a Lenovo laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/1221447/make-function-keys-behave-as-normal-on-a-lenovo-laptop) but that's not the method AFAI remember that I used. Does anybody know fo any alternate methodology for the same.

Comment: I haven't got a T440 but on my T410, T430 and now P50 on Ubuntu it's just Alt-Ctrl-F1..Alt-Ctrl-F6. In other words, the top row is the standard function keys, unless you also depress Fn.

Comment: I do have the keyboard lit up so I guess the Fn key is being used in some way, don't remember what combo was that.

Comment: Fn-space, in recent Lenovos. my P50 has a Fn-lock  (Fn-escape) with a LED. To correct my previous comment, the marking on the P50 kbd seems to indicate that the PF keys are the secondary functions. However, the keyboard is by default in Fn-lock.